# Parse multiple sections of data into separate files

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a concatenated log file with multiple logs inside that I'm trying to parse out into individual log files. I will later rename them to the date/time of each. Each log is separated by "--- LOG REPORT ---".

So far I have:

```
sed -n '/--- LOG REPORT ---/,/--- LOG REPORT ---/p' logname.log > test.out
```

However, as you can imagine, that only outputs the first instance of the pattern. I looked over the man page for sed and I'm not convinced it can output multiple files. Perhaps I could keep extracting from a file until it's empty but that seems like too much work. How I can achieve this? Maybe I should be using awk instead?

Example of input file filename.log

```
--- LOG REPORT ---
Mary
Had
A
Little
Lamb
--- LOG REPORT ---
Her
Fleece
Was
White
As
Snow
```

Desired output:

In filename_1.log

```
--- LOG REPORT ---
Mary
Had
A
Little
Lamb
```

In filename_2.log

```
--- LOG REPORT ---
Her
Fleece
Was
White
As
Snow
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like

```
awk '/--- LOG REPORT ---/ {n++;next} {print > "test"n".out"}' logname.log
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's brilliant. So 'next' is what would select the whole log data until the next occurrence, or end of file, and then n increments the filename. Nice.

Comment: The `next` just prevents the `--- LOG REPORT ---` record separator line from getting included in the output file(s). You can remove it if you want to include that - I just guessed that is redundant.

Answer (score 9):

How about this command?

```
csplit logname.log /---\ LOG\ REPORT\ ---/ {*}
```

**Testing**

```
cat logname.log
--- LOG REPORT ---
Mary
Had
A
Little
Lamb
--- LOG REPORT ---
Her
Fleece
Was
White
As
Snow
```

After running the above command, the output I get is,

```
cat xx01
--- LOG REPORT ---
Mary
Had
A
Little
Lamb
cat xx02
--- LOG REPORT ---
Her
Fleece
Was
White
As
Snow
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong tool, use either perl or awk e.g.

```
cat > splitFileByLogReport.pl <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;
$_ = <>;
$n = 0;

for $match (split(/(?=--- LOG REPORT ---)/)) {
      open(O, ">$ARGV[$argnum]" . ++$n);
      print O $match;
      close(O);
}
```

EOF

Then to run:

```
perl splitFileByLogReport.pl yourFile.txt
```

Comment: There's definitely more than one way to skin a cat. I think I'm going to stick with awk for now though.